# How to update the position of a QGraphicsElipseItem inside a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside6, pyqt6

In my `QMainWindow` I have a `QGraphicsView` which in turn displays a `QGraphicsScene`. The code is below:

```
 class circleScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    roi_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(circleScene, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._start = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.circle = None
        self.roi_closed = False
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 640, 480)
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 640, 480).normalized())
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.roi_closed:
            self.circle = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem()
            self.circle.setPen(QPen(Qt.GlobalColor.black, 5, Qt.PenStyle.SolidLine))
            self.circle.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.GlobalColor.blue, Qt.BrushStyle.FDiagPattern))
            self.circle.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
                            self.circle.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
            self.circle.setZValue(3)
            self.addItem(self.circle)
            self._start = event.scenePos()
            r = QtCore.QRectF(self._start, self._start)
            self.circle.setRect(r)
        super(circleScene, self).mousePressEvent(event)
    
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.roi_closed:
            r = QtCore.QRectF(self._start, event.scenePos()).normalized()
            self.circle.setRect(r)
        super(circleScene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.roi_signal.emit(self.circle)
        self.roi_closed = True
        # print('o circulo', self.circle.rect())
        super(circleScene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
    
    def clear(self):
        self._start = QtCore.QPointF()
        self.circle = None
        self.roi_closed = False
        super().clear()
```

In `QMainWindow`:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.scene = circleScene()
        self.scene.roi_signal.connect(self.update_roi)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 640, 480)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 640, 480).normalized())
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene, self.tab)
        self.view.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 645, 485))

    def update_roi(self, roi):
        self.roi_atual = roi
        bounding_rect = self.roi_atual.boundingRect()
        print('new position', bounding_rect)
```

`

When initially drawing the circle in the scene, the function displays a correct `boundingRect()` of the position where the circle is drawn. However, when you drag the circle with the mouse over the scene (because of the `ItemIsMovable` flag), the `boundingRect()` displayed in the `update_roi()` function remains the initial one, even if the circle displayed in the scene is in a different position. How can I update its position, so that the `boundingRect()` picks up the updated position after moving?

I tried using the `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flag, but no event is emitted with the current position

Comment: The simple answer is to use [`sceneBoundingRect()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#sceneBoundingRect). The reality is that you need to better understand the [Graphics View Coordinate System](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system), which follows the basic rules of Cartesian coordinate system, which are **relative**. The contents (the bounding rect) of a graphics item are always based on the **item position**, which defaults to `0, 0`. A `QGraphicsRectItem(20, 20, 20, 20)` will be *shown* at `20, 20`, but its position will still be `0, 0`. If the item is »

Comment: » *moved*, then only its *position* is changed, but its `boundingRect` will still be `QRectF(20, 20, 20, 20)` (adjusted to the pen size), because it's relative to that item position. If you want an item that is *actually* placed at `20, 20` but has a bounding rect starting at its origin point, then you need to create it as `(0, 0, 20, 20)` and *then* call `setPos(20, 20)`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your attention! I'm not sure I understand the point of your second comment. What I would like is that when I call the `boundingRect()` method, I get the bounding box of the circle where it is. For example, when I initially draw it on the screen at coordinates (178, 106), I get the return `QRectF(178.5, 106.5, 169.0, 166.0)`. Now suppose I moved it a little to the right, to the point (195, 106), the return from the `boundingRect()` method is still `QRectF(178.5, 106.5, 169.0, 166.0)`.

Comment: As said, the bounding rect of an item is always relative to its origin point (the `pos()`), which always defaults to `0, 0`. Check the [QGraphicsScene documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html), and you'll see that almost any `add<Something>` function always says that the item position is initialized at `(0, 0)`. To understand the difference, you need proper understanding on relative coordinate systems (see the links above and do some look up even on Wikipedia). The "visual" position of an element is always based on its coordinate system, which, in turn, can be relative too. »

Comment: » Let's try an analogy. Consider a cooking pan: you have the "container" (where the food is placed, and which should be put right above the cooktop) and a "handle" (which is where you finally "place" your hand while moving the pan). That "handle" is the *origin point* (the item's `pos()`): you use the handle to move the pan, and your brain "commands" your hand position not on the cooktop, but where the "container" will actually be (the "bounding rect", relative to the handle): the container will always be at the same position related to its handle, even when you move that handle. »

Comment: » When you create a rect/ellipse item as `(10, 10, 20, 20)`, you're actually creating a "pan container" that is `(10, 10)` *away* from its "handle" (centered a further `10, 10`, since it has a diameter of 20 and it's a perfect circle). When you move the handle (the item's `pos()`), the container geometry relative to the handle will not change, and that's why you still get the same `boundingRect()`: nothing has changed in the context of the pan: its handle is still at the same distance and angle from the "container". The "the circle where it is" is just because its position is `0, 0`.